# Cutting parts of text using other text in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs6, text, stroke

I have created a logo in adobe illustrator however as you can see the picture below I wanted to cut part of the E in airforce of using the shape of the A in advice. I normally have the logo on a white background so for the time being I added a white stroke to advice to create the illusion of cutting part of the E of as well having a bit of a gap. However now I need the logo to sit on different backgrounds I think it is time to cut part of the e off properly and not cheat by using a stroke. Can anybody show me how?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you type your words you can draw a clipping mask over the desire object you want to crop having the same skew or the same angle of the letter A which will cover the Letter E and select both the masking path and the letters you want to clip in our case you will choose "AIRFORCE" and the path you drew.
go the Object > Clipping Mask > Make

[image]